# How to debug a Splunk application with pdb?

Tags: python, splunk, pdb

How can I spawn a pdb-like debugger in a Splunk application (meaning: an application made for and ran by Splunk) ?

I have no control over the python process itself, so simply putting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the code will just result in the web app crashing.

I guess the ideal solution would be to

- either run the python part of Splunk manually, so I have control over it (I tried [this](https://www.splunk.com/blog/2014/02/03/how-to-debug-django-applications-with-pdb-pycharm-and-visual-studio.html), but it didn't work correctly; mongodb daemon wasn't starting, among other things)
- use the good old `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` breakpoint but attach to the process somehow, so I'm able to manipulate the debugger (I tried [gdb](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb), but nothing worked as expected -- perhaps I didn't use it correctly)

Comment: Note that any other tool than pdb is welcome; I'm focusing on this one as it seems to be the most simple in this case, but anything that allows me to debug will do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to debug might be a remote debugger, like `remote-pdb`.
It behaves similar as `pdb`. You can set a breakpoint, then configure the interface and a TCP port where the debugger will listen.

```py
from remote_pdb import RemotePdb
RemotePdb('127.0.0.1', 4444).set_trace()
```

After that you can simply connect to the debugger using telnet `telnet 127.0.0.1 4444`

More info: 
https://pypi.org/project/remote-pdb/